# Enumerate local SQL databases and get their version numbers

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am attempting to speed up some code that enumerates local databases and verifies their version number is appropriate for our application.  Currently the code uses WMI ([see my other question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059495/slow-wmi-managementobjectsearcher-very-slow)) but I realised that perhaps there is an alternative to WMI that would circumvent the need for optimising the current code entirely.  All I require is a list of local SQL Server databases and their version numbers.  How can I get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MSDN, its built in using `System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6t1z9x2(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That looks great but how can you force it to only look on the local machine?

Comment: @Chris you could filter down the results.

Comment: The main reason is to make it faster, but your solution (even when checking the rest of the network) works far faster than the existing solution! Out of interest, how could I detect external databases from that list?

Comment: based on the host name.